# Sorting associative array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables, associative-array

I have a particular array of objects in js that represent columns of a table.
My object is:

```
var columns = {
  "image": {
    "show": false,
    "orderable": true,
    "value": 0,
    "displayOrder":2
  },
  "name": {
    "show": true,
    "orderable": true,
    "value": 1,
    "displayOrder":0
  },
  "company": {
    "show": false,
    "orderable": false,
    "value": 2,
    "displayOrder":1
  }
}
```

I have to order the object by "displayOrder", but using a function like

```
columns.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a.displayOrder) - parseFloat(b.displayOrder); 
});
```

obviously it return an error.
How i can do this?

Comment: You have an object, and the properties of an object cannot be sorted. If you want to do this, `columns` needs to be an array.

Comment: Why you do `parseFloat` on integer? Better use `parseInt` then.

Comment: Its not possible to sort an object, but you could create an arrayofobjects like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze just copy-paste problem.

Comment: Have a look at this: [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan well but columns could be associative array where every associated value is another associative array

Comment: I don't know what that's supposed to mean. JS has no equivalent of associative arrays. There are objects (ie. what you have in the code above) and arrays. The properties of objects are transient, and cannot be sorted.

Comment: Object properties in es6 and later do have an order but are still intended as unsorted hashmaps. If you want to do sorting, while technically possible with object properties (with some restrictions), you should really use another data structure.

Comment: May be ... "I have to order the object by 'displayOrder' " should be written as "I need an array of columns object from the given object, sorted by displayOrder property value"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `.sort` only on arrays due to it is `Array.prototype` method ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)). So as an easiest solution I would prefer to reform your `columns` data from object to array:

```
var columnList = [
    {
      "key": "image",
      "value": {
          "show": false,
          "orderable": true,
          "value": 0,
          "displayOrder":2
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "name",
      "value": {
          "show": true,
          "orderable": true,
          "value": 1,
          "displayOrder":0
      } 
    },
    {
      "key": "company",
      "value": {
          "show": false,
          "orderable": false,
          "value": 2,
          "displayOrder":1
      } 
    }
];

var result = columnList.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.value.displayOrder) - parseFloat(b.value.displayOrder);  
});

console.log(result);
```

The result of `console.log` would be exactly

```
0:{key: "name", value: {…}}
1:{key: "company", value: {…}}
2:{key: "image", value: {…}}
```

---

This transformation (from `object` to `array`) could be done programmatically via `Object.keys`:

```
result = Object.keys(columns)
  .map(c => ({ key: c, value: columns[c]}))
  .sort((a, b) => a.value.displayOrder - b.value.displayOrder)
```

Here the `columns` is your initial object. With the help of `Object.keys()` and `.map()` I turn it into the array I described before, so the `.sort()` method could be called in a chain.

Comment: it works, but i have to rewrite all ther rest of code :(

Comment: I added some code to the answer to make the procedure work for `columns` object.

Comment: yes... thanks for sharing this solution, it worked very well here too!!!