# Sort objects in objects, javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, for-loop

I have an object containing objects with objects within them. Each object have an ordernum. I want to sort the objects with the lowest ordernum first.

I have used the function bellow when sorting arrays but I need help adjusting it to this structure.

```
function(a, b) {
return parseFloat(a.ordernum) - parseFloat(b.ordernum);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Objects do not have order so not sure how you are going to sort them.

Comment: I had just visited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849294/sorting-associative-array-of-objects-in-javascript#comment80646393_46849294) not too long ago... why does everyone want to sort objects today? While it is possible to sort properties with some restrictions, one should not do it.

Comment: Consider using lodash. You can use `var obj = _.mapKeys(objects, (o) => o.sortField);` and then use `_.sortBy(obj, (o) => o.sortField)` **AND** if needed, `_.reverse(obj)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Comment: Take a look at this answer about ordering in objects:
[Does JavaScript guarantee object property order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sort + convert to an array then ?:

```
const result =
 Object.values( yourobject )
  .sort((a,b)=> a.ordernum - b.ordernum );
```